# Shakersort c++, error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int* - I can't find where I mixed integer and pointer to integers

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int up=18;
int realArray[up]={12,28,75,16,66,6,121,19,195,56,108,221,19,93,104,127,73,22}; //definition of a random array
void shakersort(int formArray[up]);//shakersort declared
void tauschen(int *a,int *b){int zw= *a; *a=*b; *b=zw;}

int main()
{
    shakersort(realArray[up]); //here happens the error of the conversion 
    return 0;
}

void shakersort(int formArray[up]){ //the code
for(int i=0; i<up/2;i++){
        for (i=0; i<up-1;i++){
            if(formArray[i]>formArray[i+1]){
                tauschen(&formArray[i], &formArray[i+1]);
            }
}
        for (int k=up-1; k>0;i--){
            if(formArray[k]>formArray[k-1]){
                tauschen(&formArray[k], &formArray[k-1]);
            }
}
}

}
```

Not sure why there is a conversion error. Used the same code at declaration and application so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: The name of the array is "realArray", not "realArray[up]".

Answer (score 1):

`up` is an `int` with value `18` so in this line

```
shakersort(realArray[up]);
```

you are basically writing

```
shakersort(realArray[18]);
```

which will index a single value from your array (which also happens to be out of bounds, which would therefore be undefined behavior). Instead just pass the array itself

```
shakersort(realArray);
```

though I would encourage you to look into using `std::vector` instead

```
void shakersort(std::vector<int>& formArray);
```

so you don't need a global variable floating around to determine the array size, you can just use `formArray.size()`